# PC wont boot on the right hdd/ssd

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

My PC won't boot on the right drive, doesn't matter even if I go into bios and choose my SSD (where Windows 10 and everything else is installed), it still tries to boot from my old HDD that I used on my laptop.

Does it have something to do with all the old things on the HDD? I'm pretty sure that I have a whole working operating system on it and a lot of other files. 
If I'm in the middle of the bootup and I pull out the cables to the HDD (that should not be booted from) the PC boot process stops immediately. And one last thing I'm stuck at the windows 10 startup thingy when its loading windows.

Comment: Are you saying you simply swapped HDD's and are trying to boot to the SDD? Or did you put the SSD into your PC and then do a fresh install?

Comment: my ssd already have the operating system and i do not want a fresh install, my ssd only have 120 gb and i needed more so i put in a hdd. and im good att pc's but still i couldnt figur out what made the pc boot the hdd all the time. even when i was in bios and pressed on the ssd disc as to boot up with immidieatly it still booted up from the hdd

Comment: Did you install the Windows on the SSD while the HDD was connected to the system ? It could be that the SSD is missing the System Reserved partition. You can check in Windows Disk Management. ?You should also try disconnecting the HDD from the system and test if the SSD Os will boot then.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you simply swap drives from one PC to the next, and try to boot it does not work. The main issue is that the wrong hardware drivers are installed and it causes issues. There is also a chance that your current installation will become corrupt by swapping from one PC to the next. You can try booting into safe mode with networking and see what happens, but there is no guarantee that it will work. You can try booting into safe mode and see if the hardware wizard will have you install the new drivers.

If you do a fresh install with the SSD, you could still plug in the HDD and access it as a secondary drive. This would allow you to transfer files that you may want to move from the HDD to the SSD.